# How to Concrete a 2D Python List to 1D

Tags: python, python-3.x

A given 2d list say `[['D', 'S'], ['A', 'M'], ['I', 'N'], ['C', 'F'], ['E', 'T']]` is needed to concrete to all string like DAICE, DAICT, DAIFE, DAIFT, ..., SMNFT (1st list items + 2nd list items + 3rd list items + 4th list items + 5 list items) and store them to a new 1d list.

Anyone please help! Many thanks!

I tried using for loop but didn't figure out...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

lst = [['D', 'S'], ['A', 'M'], ['I', 'N'], ['C', 'F'], ['E', 'T']]

lst2 = list(map(''.join, product(*lst)))

print(lst2)
```

Try the above snippet.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code and work exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @PiggyZ, I would be glad if you accept my answer as the correct one! Have a great day ahead.